# How do I list macports package dependencies and the size of each dependency

Tags: macos, unix, macports

I want to install a package (on macports) and want to know how much data i'm going to use to install it.
I know that if use "port deps " it lists the dependencies. But i want to know the size of each package.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible; you can get the size of an installed package, but there's no way to tell before install how big it will be. Pre-compiled binary packages are stored on remote servers in compressed format. These are not always available as well, so ports are often compiled from source.